# How do I upgrade tensorflow from version1 to version2 on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, pip, tensorflow2.0

I tried upgrading using `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow` and it gets upgraded to `1.14` version. This is what is being displayed at the beginning of the installation,

> Collecting tensorflow   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/de/f0/96fb2e0412ae9692dbf400e5b04432885f677ad6241c088ccc5fe7724d69/tensorflow-1.14.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl

Also tried using `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow==2.0.0-rc0` but in vain.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: if you follow the instructions contained here can you upgrade to 1.15 https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Comment: I am looking to upgrade to version2 (TF2)-- stated in the question title. Thanks.

Comment: The latest supported version on Google Cloud Platform of tf is 1.15 ... if this is not intended for use on Google Cloud Platform please remove the google-cloud-platform tag. t.f 2.x is not yet supported

Comment: Alright.Thank you @PaddyPopeye